# Using custom boundaries in high map

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, geojson, highmaps

I am trying to use highchart in r. I just downloaded this map https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/nz/nz-all.js . As per the documentation, seems like it is using EPSG 2193. "crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:2193"}} . And it looks like this - [3871,7816],[3871,7778],[3832,7773].....

However it does not have all the regions I need, but I have those regional boundaries as lat/long multi polygon in this format [174.3611,-35.7754],[174.3594,-35.7388],[174.3251,-35.7238],[174.3361,-35.7537].....

Provided numbers are just examples, how do I add these boundaries in to the map provided in high map library. I just read this link which says, https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/latlon to mention the proj4string separately for that particular region. But I don't know what projection system I have to use in this case. Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see the vignette https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/highcharter/vignettes/charting-maps.html?

```
hcmap("countries/nz/nz-all")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But as I said, I need to add custom regions in it. I need to know how to add our own region in this map.

Comment: Cool. That gives some information. Let me try that and get back. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

### **JavaScript case**

Refer to this **live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/sv78kux9/

It shows how to use points in lat/lon format in `mappoint` series:

```
{
  name: 'London',
  lat: 51.507222,
  lon: -0.1275
}, {
  name: 'Belfast',
  lat: 54.597,
  lon: -5.93
}
```

The trick is to set the `lineWidth` to non zero integer and color the area between the points using CSS:

```
// JS options
className: 'custom',

// CSS
.custom .highcharts-graph {
  fill: red
}
```

To make it look more like an area set `color:` to `'transparent'` for the line and disable hover, data labels and tooltip for this series.